# ReadLn working with WideString (utf-8 files)

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-7, widestring

I use delphi 7.

I need to read a utf-8 file line by line, each line contain a word and its weight (a number)
So I need to read every next line, then divide a line by a separator (tab char) and save this in memory.

So,

1) is there a library to work with utf-8 files in Delphi (3-rd party maybe)

2) will functions operate ok with widestring? I use PosEx. So, if they won't, can you also give a link to 3-rd party library to work with widestrings?

Answer (score 4):

If it is really UTF-8 that you are dealing with, then you should not need anything special as far as reading and processing them.  You should be able to treat them as pchar or even as a normal Delphi 7 string. If you try to show the contents in some kind of message box, then you may need to do some conversions.  For example, I don't believe the Delphi 7 message box method would display UTF-8 strings correctly if the string contained any byte values over 127 (0x7f).  For something like that, you would need to convert to UTF-16 and call the Windows API MessageBoxW or something similar. Otherwise, though, UTF-8 strings can be treated in many situations the same as single byte ANSI strings.

I don't think UTF-8 is typically referred to as "widestring".  I might be wrong, but I think that typically means UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

If your file is encoded as UTF-8, and the characters you're looking for are ASCII, then there's no need to use `WideString` at all. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, and any ASCII character is guaranteed not to interfere with the special encoding used for other characters in UTF-8. The number characters `0` through `9` and the tab character are all ASCII.

The [JCL](http://jcl.sf.net/) comes with various functions and classes for dealing with Unicode, if you find you really need to use them.

Answer (score 1):

WideString is an UTF-16 implementation (a COM BSTR compatible one), it can't store UTF-8 strings, if you assign an 8 bit string it will be converted to UTF-16. But unless you use explicitly the proper conversion function, Delphi will interpret the 8 bit string using the current codepage.

An UTF-8 string can be stored in a Delphi AnsiString (the default string type in Delphi 7), but string manipulation functions are designed for ANSI codepages, not UTF-8. The difference is that UTF-8 is a multi byte character set. But the first 127 ANSI characters, more than one byte is needed to encode a given "character", while many ANSI codepages (especially those for European languages) only require one byte, encoding only 255 "characters" (while UTF-8 can encode the whole Unicode set).

If you're just looking for the tab character AFAIK you could use simply an AnsiString, but you have to ensure that any byte above $80 you may need to look for is not part of a multibyte sequence. If you have more complex processing needs, it may be easier to find libraries working on UTF-16 strings than UTF-8. As Rob Kennedy said, JCL is a good starting point as a free library implementing UTF string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

If most of your input is UTF-8, it *might* be worthwhile to change your codepage on startup from the "default" to utf8 (codepage 65001). This will make all ansistring->widestring conversions effectively become a lossless utf-8->utf-16.

With D7, you will need a set of so called "unicode" components, components that base themselves on the winapi -W functions. Delphi's own components only do this with the watershed D2009 release that switches the default string type to UTF-16.

If you want to heavily invest in Unicode support, upgrading might be a smart thing to do

Answer (score 0):

You could simply read the file as-is into a normal TStringList via its LoadFrom...() methods, then loop through the list as needed.  If loading the entire file into memory at one time is not an option, then you can open the file using a TFileStream and then use the TStreamReader.ReadLine() method to read the stream line-by-line.

If you need to decode a given UTF-8 sequence to UTF-16 for processing, then I would suggest using the Win32 API MultiByteToWideChar() function directly, only because the RTL's UTF8Decode() function has a broken UTF-8 implementation in older Delphi versions (not sure about D7, but it definately does in D6).

The nice thing about either loading approach is that they are both encoding-aware in D2009 and later, which means that if you ever upgrade, you can make a couple of very small code changes to tell the RTL that the data is UTF-8, and it will decode it to UTF-16 for you automatically, and then the rest of your processing code can remain the same (assuming you are not doing anything that is Ansi-specific).